# What is the relation between block-pulse function and Heaviside Step function?

Tags: step-function

**Block-pulse function:**

[image]

**Heaviside-Step function**

[vikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

Are they the same functions? Is the block pulse function just the discrete form of the Heaviside step func. ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Your block-pulse functions are supported (i.e. nonzero) on a bounded set, while the Heaviside function is nonzero for all large inputs.